# Are SignalR connectionIDs hub-specific?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

If I have several hubs, and connect a single JavaScript client to all of them, will the context ConnectionID be the same between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I didn't know the answer, so I tested it using [this example](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) by changing it a bit.

The Hub classes:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub {
    public void Send(string name, string message) {
        string cid = Context.ConnectionId;
        Clients.All.sendMessage(name, message);
    }
}

public class ChatHub2 : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        string cid = Context.ConnectionId;
        Clients.All.sendMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

The `page.html` connecting to the hubs:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
var chat2 = $.connection.chatHub2;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Call the Send method on the hub.
    chat.server.send('Me', 'Message to 1');
    chat2.server.send('Me', 'Message to 2');
});
```

I set breakpoints on the Hub methods and both are called, and `Context.ConnectionId` are the same. That's what I was expecting. Give it a try!

It makes sense, it supposed to use the same connection to send the message over.